# редактор картинок на Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-player, photo

задача - открыть изображение с компьютера, добавть логотип в углу, выдать запрос на скачивание редактированого изображение обратно на компьютер

возможно ли это и как в кратце это сделать?

Action Script позволяет подгружать внешние изображения. но вот объединять их... я не смог найти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Можно просто добавить загруженные объекты друг на друга через addChild(), или на готовый пустой объект Sprite

2) Создаете пустой объект BitmapData, и на нем рисуете BitmapData.draw() уже загруженных изображений.